# Detection of key-point , ORB , opencv

Tags: opencv, math, open-source, orb

I'm not sure that I understand correctly what is opensource. I searched here to find answers but I didn't found anyone that asked a similar question.

How can I see the source code of the "detect" function in the file "features.hpp". 
I'm looking for the math calculations of the algorithm ORB.
Is it open for everyone how wants to see it?

Just to be more accurate and sure that I'm clear enough, you can find the function's declaration ("detect") is inside "objdetect.hpp"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the function implementations are typically written in `.cpp` files. The `.h` or `.hpp` files are header files which contain only the function signature and type declarations.

A good starting point for the ORB detector is [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/orb.cpp#L956).